# Writing a function of two variables as a function in one variable

Tags: python, arguments, function-prototypes, argument-unpacking

Let's say I have the following function that is in 2 variables   -

```
def banana(x,y):
    return exp(((-x**2/200))-0.5*(y+0.05*(x**2) - 100*0.05)**2)
```

and I would like to write it as -

```
def banana(x):
```

where x here is a vector of two variables; if that's possible?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be something like

```
def banana(x):
    return exp(((-x[0]**2/200))-0.5*(x[1]+0.05*(x[0]**2) - 100*0.05)**2)
```

Comment: Backticks are only for code-formatting blocks of less than a line. Use four-space indents for multi-line blocks to get formatting as a contiguous block and color syntax rendering.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thank you!

Comment: NP. (I took the liberty of fixing that up myself here; you can look at the edit history to see the difference).

Answer (score 3):

Unpack the args in the beginning of your function:

```
def banana(args):
    x, y = args
    return exp(((-x**2/200))-0.5*(y+0.05*(x**2) - 100*0.05)**2)
```

or directly in the definition line:

```
def banana((x, y)):
    return exp(((-x**2/200))-0.5*(y+0.05*(x**2) - 100*0.05)**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible:

```
def _banana(x):
    return banana(*x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

```
def banana(vector):
    x, y = vector
    return exp(((-x**2/200))-0.5*(y+0.05*(x**2) - 100*0.05)**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course it's possible.
You can use either a list or a tuple. Put you two variables into a list or a tuple

```
x = [5, 7] # A list
x = (5, 7) # A tuple
```

And you function should then be like that:

```
def banana(x):
    x, y = x # Unpacking
    return exp(((-x**2/200))-0.5*(y+0.05*(x**2) - 100*0.05)**2)
```

See more at https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score -1):

you can write with lists

```
def banana(x):
    return exp(((-x[0]**2/200))-0.5*(x[1]+0.05*(x[0]**2) - 100*0.05)**2)
```